# Firefox rendering elements incorrectly (Hardware Acceleration issue)

Tags: html, css, firefox

I built this wizard using only CSS. But is giving problem in new versions of Firefox. In Google Chrome and IE 9+ works perfectly. The problem seems to be the pseudo elements `:after` and `:before`

Here is a picture of the error:

[image]

And here a picture of how it works in Chrome and should work in Firefox:

[image]

Fiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/2jZmr/1/

**Update:** I saw that the problem is not only with the version of Firefox, tested on two different computers with the same version of Firefox (v28) and one worked and the other did not. I've reinstalled Firefox on my machine and the problem persists. I also tested it on Firefox in Android 4.4.2 and it worked normally.

**Update2:** When I open firefox in security mode the error does not happen. But just disable all plugins, add-ons and themes does not correct the error.

**Update3:** I found the reason of error. The problem is Firefox hardware acceleration.

I follow this steps:

1. At the top of the Firefox window, click on the Firefox button and then select Options
2. Select the Advanced panel and the General tab.
3. Uncheck Use hardware acceleration when available.
4. At the top of the Firefox window, click on the Firefox button and then select Exit
5. Start Firefox the way you normally do.

But is it possible to change the css or perform some code via javascript to run in firefox with hardware acceleration turned on?

The alternative that will follow if not, will use images instead of CSS3.

Edit: My Firefox is now at version 32.0 and the problem continues.

Comment: It works fine on FF 27.0.1

Comment: I tested on two different machines, one with version 27.0.1 and the other with version 28 and both the error happened.

Comment: I've checked the jsFiddle link you've provided, and it looks perfect here.

Comment: On my machine opening fiddle in firefox I get the error.

Comment: Works fine with FFv28 on Linux and Windows XP. (Also tested FF v 25 - both fine). What OS are you on? If you want you can update with information from `about:` page in Firefox. Such as `Build identifier:` and / or `about:buildconfig`

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 64bits. I test in other two machines with the same system. Some coworkers tested for me, for most of them the error occurred, both using Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Firefox about: Compile Informantion: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0

Comment: Firebox about:buildconfig ->  Build platform target i686-pc-mingw32, Configure Arguments: --enable-crashreporter --enable-release --enable-update-channel=release --enable-update-packaging --enable-jemalloc --with-google-api-keyfile=/c/builds/gapi.data --enable-warnings-as-errors --enable-official-branding

Comment: Thanks for update. FYI. It works fine with/without HW-acceleration on 32-bit Linux and Windows. (FF v28) I can test on Win-64bit 7 later.

Comment: I've got a machine with the same configuration as you, @LeonardoDelfino -- here it doesn't show the error. It's 64bit Win/32bit Fx. There are other issues with image rendering on this machine, but your jsFiddle looks fine.

Comment: On my personal computer the error does not happen only on my work computer. I believe the cause of the error must be related to computer hardware and not the system.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the problem on my FF, but what you can try is to double the ':' before the pseudo-element :

Sometimes you will see double colons (::) instead of just one (:). This is part of CSS3 and an attempt to distinguish between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements. Most browsers support both values.

Note: ::selection always starts with double colons (::).
You can use only one pseudo-element in a selector. It must appear after the simple selectors in the statement.

src : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

Answer (score 1):

Normal Class in CSS:

```
.myClass { 
    margin-top: 0px; 
}
```

Use this CSS hack for Firefox:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
    .myClass { 
         margin-top: -9px; 
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code and tried to run it in firefox but the problem is same as you said, then add

> .wizard-steps li.active:after { border-left: 24px solid #555; display:
>   block; }

and it works on my browser. Could you please check it?

Comment: I tried and did not work well. In your browser is rendering the wrong is exactly like the image I posted?

Comment: it working perfectly on Firfox 28.0, chorme Version 33.0.1750.154 m. Can you please send me url your url so that i can check through.

Answer (score -2):

Why use before and after when you could use :

```
display: block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
float: left;
```

and stop using position relative witch in most of the cases ruins responsive or css design.

Try to place your elements in a single div width procentual size : .box { width: 100%; display: block; float: left;}

and position the other elements inside the .box div with float: left; display block; margin or padding left and width in % and see what happens ;)

Comment: You really read the question and saw the code? The utilization of pseudo selectors: after and: before is to add items to the edges. I lose if I remove the effect of edges. My problem is not the position, but rendering.